Guideline 3.1.5 - Business - Payments - Cryptocurrencies App store
Guideline 3.1.5 - Business - Payments - Cryptocurrencies
Your app facilitates the transmission of a virtual currency but does not meet all our requirements for apps with cryptocurrency exchange services:

The storefronts you selected in App Store Connect include locations where you or your third-party service provider(s) have not provided supporting evidence of permissions, registrations, and/or licenses to distribute an app with exchange services.

These requirements help prevent fraudulent transactions from occurring in exchange apps on the App Store.
we are crypto exchange Licensed with Lithuanian VASP license. but 10 times got rejected trying to publish our Application on the App Store,
maybe someone faced the same issue? We are attaching an extract from the register of legal entities
We tried to choose different availability regions. 1st EU members 2nd only Lithuania
